# want to search name from database instead of last field in database

Tags: android

**DBhelper Class**

```
 public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    private static final String DB_NAME_TWO = "Loan_TWO.db";
    private static final int VERSION = 1;
    private SQLiteDatabase mDb;

    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME_TWO, null, VERSION);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {


        //      db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_COLLEGES + " ( "
        //              + COL_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
        //              + COL_NAME + " text, "
        //              + COL_ADDRESS + " text);");


        db.execSQL("create table " + LOAN_TABLE + " ( "
                + ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
                + Name + " text,"
                + START_DATE + " text, "
                + END_DATE + " text, "
                + LOAN_AMOUNT + " integer, "
                + RATE_OF_INTEREST + " integer ," 
                + FINAL_AMOUNT + " integer) ;");



        db.execSQL("create table " + AMOUNT_TABLE_ONE + " ( "
                + AMOUNT_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
                + ID + " integer, "
                + Name + " text, "
                + AMOUNT + " text, "
                + BALANCE_AMOUNT + " text, "
                + NEXT_DATE + " text, "
                + TODAYS_DATE + " text); ");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + LOAN_TABLE);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + AMOUNT_TABLE_ONE);

        onCreate(db);
    }
}
```

**SearchActivity class**

```
    public class SearchActivity extends Activity {

    private EditText Search_By_Name;
    private ArrayList<Personal_loan> array;
    private ArrayAdapter<Personal_loan> adapter;
    private ListView listView;
    SQLiteDatabase db;

    private DBHelper helper;
    Personal_loan p = new Personal_loan();

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);
        Search_By_Name = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.SearchName);

        array = new ArrayList<Personal_loan>();

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Personal_loan>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    getData();

    }
    private void getData() {
        helper = new DBHelper(this);
        db = helper.getWritableDatabase();

        String columns[] = new String[] {ID,Name,START_DATE,END_DATE,LOAN_AMOUNT,RATE_OF_INTEREST,FINAL_AMOUNT};
        Cursor cursor = db.query( true, LOAN_TABLE, columns,"Name=?",new String[]{"Amit"}, null, null, null, null, null);

        if (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {

                p = new Personal_loan();
                p.id = cursor.getInt(0);
                p.name = cursor.getString(1);
                p.sd = cursor.getString(2);
                p.ed = cursor.getString(3);
                p.la = cursor.getDouble(4);
                p.roi = cursor.getFloat(5);
                p.amt=cursor.getString(6);
                array.add(p);
                cursor.moveToNext();
                Search_By_Name.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) 
                    {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    } 

                    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                            int after) 
                    {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }

                    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) 
                    {

                        SearchActivity.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(s);
                    }
                });

            }

            cursor.close();
            db.close();
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }       

    }


   public void onBackPressed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent i=new Intent(SearchActivity.this,FirstActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

**Personal_Loan**

```
public class Personal_loan {
    public int id;
    String name;
    String sd;
    String ed;
    Double la;
    float roi;
    String amt;


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return " Person ID =" + id + "\n Name =" + name + "\n Start Date =" + sd
                + "\n End Date =" + ed + "\n Loan Amount =" + la + "\n Rate Of Interest =" + roi +"\n Loan Final Amount= "+ amt  ;
    }
}
```

I want to search name from database and filter the list according to name field which typed on `edittext`, the above code search the list by last field i.e Final Amount, but I want to search it by name not by Final Amount.

Comment: Do you want the query for fetching the names based on the name you have typed in the edit text or You want to use the AutoCompleteTextView???

Comment: yes , i am using edit text not AutoCompleteTextView, from above cod eit search by Final Amount, if i removed that field the search will not work

Comment: Post your Personal_loan code

Comment: please check the above edited code

Comment: @PriyankaAmrutkar take custom adapter

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use below code by using custom adapter:

```
public class SearchActivity extends Activity {

private EditText Search_By_Name;
private ArrayList<Personal_loan> array;
private ListAdapter<Personal_loan> adapter;
private ListView listView;
SQLiteDatabase db;

private DBHelper helper;
Personal_loan p = new Personal_loan();

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);
    Search_By_Name = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.SearchName);

    array = new ArrayList<Personal_loan>();

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    getData();
    adapter = new ListAdapter(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, array);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    Search_By_Name.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) 
                {
                  SearchActivity.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(s);

                } 

                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                        int after) 
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) 
                {


                }
            });


}
private void getData() {
    helper = new DBHelper(this);
    db = helper.getWritableDatabase();

    String columns[] = new String[] {ID,Name,START_DATE,END_DATE,LOAN_AMOUNT,RATE_OF_INTEREST,FINAL_AMOUNT};
    Cursor cursor = db.query( true, LOAN_TABLE,null, null, null, null, null);

    if (cursor!=null) {
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            p = new Personal_loan();
            p.id = cursor.getInt(0);
            p.name = cursor.getString(1);
            p.sd = cursor.getString(2);
            p.ed = cursor.getString(3);
            p.la = cursor.getDouble(4);
            p.roi = cursor.getFloat(5);
            p.amt=cursor.getString(6);
            array.add(p);
         }
       }
        cursor.close();
        db.close();

 }

public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Intent i=new Intent(SearchActivity.this,FirstActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

ListAdapter.java:

```
public class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Personal_loan> {

private Context context;
private ArrayList<Personal_loan> array;
private ArrayList<Personal_loan> aListDump;

public ListAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId,
        ArrayList<Personal_loan> array) {
    super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, array);
    this.context = context;
    this.array = array;
    aListDump = array;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return array.size();
}

@Override
public Personal_loan getItem(int position) {
    return array.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}
@Override
public Filter getFilter() {

    Filter filter = new Filter() {

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
                FilterResults results) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            array = (ArrayList<Personal_loan>) results.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        // getting results based on the search text view text
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
            String seq = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();
            ArrayList<Personal_loan> list = new ArrayList<Personal_loan>();
            if (seq.trim().length() == 0 || seq == null) {
                results.count = aListDump.size();
                results.values = aListDump;
                list.addAll(aListDump);
            } else {
                for (Personal_loan bean : aListDump) {
                    if (bean.name.toLowerCase().contains(seq.toLowerCase()))
                        list.add(bean);
                }
            }
            results.count = list.size();
            results.values = list;
            return results;
        }
    };
    return filter;
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks , i got solution

Comment: This answer is clearly wrong and should not be accepted. If binding a list view towards a database, a CursorAdapter should be used. Data should not be manually retrieved from the database and put into an array. If the amount of data grows, you will run out of memory and get performance issues.

Comment: i am not using large amount of data so i put data into array n used custom adapter for filter.

Answer (score 1):

You are making a query with no WHERE clause at all, so you are effectively listing all records in the table.
Go look at the documentation for the [query](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query(boolean,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.os.CancellationSignal)) method and use appropriate selection and selectionArgs to fulfill your needs.

Edit: It seems to me you updated the question. You have a sqlite database that you want to list in a listview, but you are manually iterating through the cursor, adding items into an array, and then using an ArrayAdapter on the listview. You should instead use a CursorAdapter, or even SimpleCursorAdapter, and scrap the array altogether. Pass a suitable Cursor holding the query parameters you want, including a suitable where clause explained in the link above, into the adapter.

As I interpreted the original question, it was about how to filter records by name, not about how to create a list adapter.

Answer (score 1):

You should really try using a `SimpleCursorAdapter` instead of an `ArrayAdapter` and use `adapter.swapCursor(cursor)` with a new cursor with the correct query on `afterTextChanged`.

Optionally, it is recommended to use [loaders](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html) for any db access so you wont slow down the main ui thread.

Answer (score 0):

```
Use query like

String query = "SELECT * FROM  AMOUNT_TABLE_ONE  WHERE Name LIKE 'your_expected_name%'"
Cursor cursor = db.rawquery(query,null);
cursor.moveToFirst();
```

Comment: i used this query "Select * From LOAN_TABLE WHERE Name LIKE  ' Search_By_Name.getText().toString() '"

Comment: What you got after using this query.

Comment: i will not get the answer

Comment: Did you find the documentation for the query method in my answer? This answer tells you everything you need to know. Assuming you know sql it's very straightforward to add a parameter for where name=xxx. Did you try this and still have problems?

Comment: i found the query method... but the still i have problems.i used this "Cursor cursor = db.query( true, LOAN_TABLE, columns,"Name=?",new String[]{"name given in edittext"}, null, null, null, null, null)"

Comment: @Akash, i used this query,"Cursor cursor = db.query( true, LOAN_TABLE, columns,"Name=?",new String[]{"Amit"}, null, null, null, null, null)", now it shows the records By Amit name, but the problem is i have given this name in query, not on runtime edittext box

Comment: @Akash, i used the above the query , it will not display the search result